# Seems I wrecked dpkg

Tags: package-management, dpkg

For some reason I deleted the file: sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/config.dat

And then dpkg started complaining:

```
~ > sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up shim-signed (1.32~14.04.2+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up phonon:amd64 (4:4.7.80-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04) ...
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package phonon:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-runtime:
 kde-runtime depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kde-runtime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdepasswd:
 kdepasswd depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kdepasswd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-workspace-bin:
 kde-workspace-bin depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 kde-workspace-bin depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kde-workspace-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemsettings:
 systemsettings depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemsettings (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkcompactdisc4:
 libkcompactdisc4 depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkcompactdisc4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-window-manager:
 kde-window-manager depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kde-window-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-window-manager-common:
 kde-window-manager-common depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kde-window-manager-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of konsole:
 konsole depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package konsole (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkonq-common:
 libkonq-common depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkonq-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dolphin:
 dolphin depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 dolphin depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dolphin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-workspace:
 kde-workspace depends on kde-workspace-bin (>= 4:4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package kde-workspace-bin is not configured yet.
 kde-workspace depends on kde-window-manager (>= 4:4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2) | kde-window-manager-active (>= 4:4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package kde-window-manager is not configured yet.
  Package kde-window-manager-active is not installed.
 kde-workspace depends on systemsettings (>= 4:4.11.11-0ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package systemsettings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kde-workspace (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkonq5abi1:
 libkonq5abi1 depends on libkonq-common (>= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libkonq-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkonq5abi1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-style-oxygen:
 kde-style-oxygen depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kde-style-oxygen (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libakonadi-contact4:
 libakonadi-contact4 depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libakonadi-contact4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plasma-netbook:
 plasma-netbook depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plasma-netbook (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libokularcore4:
 libokularcore4 depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libokularcore4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkcddb4:
 libkcddb4 depends on libkcompactdisc4; however:
  Package libkcompactdisc4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkcddb4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of okular:
 okular depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 okular depends on libokularcore4 (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libokularcore4 is not configured yet.
 okular depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package okular (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer0.10-qapt:
 gstreamer0.10-qapt depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer0.10-qapt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plasma-desktop:
 plasma-desktop depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plasma-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-desktop:
 kubuntu-desktop depends on dolphin; however:
  Package dolphin is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on gstreamer0.10-qapt; however:
  Package gstreamer0.10-qapt is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kde-window-manager; however:
  Package kde-window-manager is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kde-workspace; however:
  Package kde-workspace is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kdepasswd; however:
  Package kdepasswd is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on konsole; however:
  Package konsole is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on okular; however:
  Package okular is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on plasma-desktop; however:
  Package plasma-desktop is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on plasma-netbook; however:
  Package plasma-netbook is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-desktop depends on systemsettings; however:
  Package systemsettings is not configu
dpkg: error processing package kubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ark:
 ark depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 ark depends on libkonq5abi1 (>= 4:4.6.1); however:
  Package libkonq5abi1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ark (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kio-audiocd:
 kio-audiocd depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 kio-audiocd depends on libkcddb4 (>= 4:4.3.4); however:
  Package libkcddb4 is not configured yet.
 kio-audiocd depends on libkcompactdisc4 (>= 4:4.8.80); however:
  Package libkcompactdisc4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kio-audiocd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ksysguard:
 ksysguard depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ksysguard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kmix:
 kmix depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kmix (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pykde4:
 python3-pykde4 depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 python3-pykde4 depends on phonon; however:
  Package phonon:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pykde4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of khelpcenter4:
 khelpcenter4 depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package khelpcenter4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdepim-runtime:
 kdepim-runtime depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 kdepim-runtime depends on libakonadi-contact4 (>= 4:4.13.3); however:
  Package libakonadi-contact4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kdepim-runtime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lightdm-kde-greeter:
 lightdm-kde-greeter depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lightdm-kde-greeter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of klipper:
 klipper depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package klipper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ksnapshot:
 ksnapshot depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ksnapshot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qapt-batch:
 qapt-batch depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qapt-batch (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libakonadi-calendar4:
 libakonadi-calendar4 depends on libakonadi-contact4 (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.3); however:
  Package libakonadi-contact4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libakonadi-calendar4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of audiocd-kio:
 audiocd-kio depends on kio-audiocd; however:
  Package kio-audiocd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package audiocd-kio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plasma-widgets-workspace:
 plasma-widgets-workspace depends on kdepim-runtime; however:
  Package kdepim-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plasma-widgets-workspace (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plasma-dataengines-workspace:
 plasma-dataengines-workspace depends on kdepim-runtime; however:
  Package kdepim-runtime is not configured yet.
 plasma-dataengines-workspace depends on libakonadi-calendar4 (>= 4:4.10.80); however:
  Package libakonadi-calendar4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plasma-dataengines-workspace (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-kde:
 software-properties-kde depends on python3-pykde4; however:
  Package python3-pykde4 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-kde depends on qapt-batch; however:
  Package qapt-batch is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-kde (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
 phonon:amd64
 grub-efi-amd64
 kde-runtime
 kdepasswd
 kde-workspace-bin
 systemsettings
 libkcompactdisc4
 kde-window-manager
 kde-window-manager-common
 konsole
 libkonq-common
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 dolphin
 kde-workspace
 libkonq5abi1
 kde-style-oxygen
 libakonadi-contact4
 plasma-netbook
 libokularcore4
 libkcddb4
 okular
 gstreamer0.10-qapt
 plasma-desktop
 kubuntu-desktop
 ark
 kio-audiocd
 ksysguard
 kmix
 python3-pykde4
 khelpcenter4
 kdepim-runtime
 lightdm-kde-greeter
 klipper
 ksnapshot
 qapt-batch
 libakonadi-calendar4
 audiocd-kio
 plasma-widgets-workspace
 plasma-dataengines-workspace
 software-properties-kde
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try this `dpkg-reconfigure debconf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this answer [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1823695), steps were:

1. Rebuild debconf's own debconf database entries:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf
   ```
2. Rebuild the debconf database for everything else:

   ```
   for pkg in $(dpkg-query --show | awk '{print $1}'); do echo ; echo "--> $pkg" ; echo ; dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive --priority=critical $pkg < /dev/null ; done
   ```